# Find which collection view cell is linked to my table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I'm looking for your help for my association between a tableview and a collection view.

I've got a CollectionView with 6 horizontal scrollable cells.
In each cell, I would like to put a table view.

For each tableView, I need to know in which cell I am to put my wanted data.

Actually, I make my code work for displaying tableView inside the cells but I'm blocked for finding in which collection view cell I am.

BTW, my Meal_vc_cell controller is actually Empty, it just has a simple outlet. Nothing else.

Here is my code

```
class TrainFoodPlanViewController: BaseViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let train_meals_list: [String] = ["breakfast", "snack_1", "pre_intra_post", "lunch", "snack_2", "diner"]

    @IBOutlet weak var trainCollectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Food Plan"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return train_meals_list.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! Meal_vc_cell

        cell.meal_number.text = train_meals_list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do
[image]

Comment: The collection view cell should be the tableview data source; You assign the appropriate array to a property of the collection view

Comment: You could give you cell's contentView a tag associated with it's position in the collectionView(`cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row`) and give that tag to the tableView inside the cell(`tableView.tag = cell.contentView.tag`).  Then in your tableView's delegate use that tag to know which collectionViewCell it is associated with(`switch tableView.tag { ... }`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved. My recommendation is to subclass `UITableView` and add a `parentCollectionViewIndexPath` property

```
class MyCustomTableView: UITableView {
    var parentCollectionViewIndexPath: IndexPath?
}
```

I'm assuming **Meal_vc_cell** has an outlet to the relevant tableView. Change that tableView's type to `MyCustomTableView`

```
class Meal_vc_cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: MyCustomTableView
}
```

**Note:** *If you're using storyboard, don't forget to update the tableView's class in storyboard as well*

Now, just set `parentCollectionViewIndexPath` in the collectionView's `cellForItemAt` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! Meal_vc_cell
    cell.tableView.parentCollectionViewIndexPath = indexPath
    return cell
}
```